# ¿Como elimino los bordes en una matriz con numeros aleatorios y enteros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

Quiero saber como puedo excluir los bordes 0 y 101 para que estos no me salgan en la matriz a la hora de ejecutarla. Gracias!
Aquí les dejo el enunciado que se me dio para poder resolver la pregunta

Llene cada matriz con numeros aleatorios, todos distintos y enteros que esten entre 0 y 101 excluyendo bordes. Para hacer lo anterior, puede utilizar la funcion randint que se encuentra en la librería random. DEBE SABER COMO IMPORTAR LA FUNCION. Tambien puede utilizar np.random.unifom() y redondear el elemento resultante.

Y lo siguiente es lo que realice

```
from random import randint
def llenar_matriz(n):
    matriz1 = []
    matriz2 = []
    matriz3 = []

    for r in range(20):
        fila = []

        for c in range(20):
            fila.append(randint(0, 101))

        
            matriz1.append(fila)
            matriz2.append(fila)
            matriz3.append(fila)
    
    return matriz1
    return matriz2
    return matriz3


resultado1 = llenar_matriz(20)
print(resultado1)

resultado2 = llenar_matriz(20)
print(resultado2)

resultado3 = llenar_matriz(20)
print(resultado3)
```

No se si también hay una forma de acortar todo este codigo, solo soy principante en el tema de la programación. Gracias!

Comment: Simplemente usa `randint(1, 100)` para obtener numeros entre 1 y 100 inclusive, y así no te saldrán el 0 ni el 101.

Comment: La función tiene un parámetro que no usa para nada. Después del primer `return`, se termina la función (los dos `return` siguientes nunca se ejecutan). Si quieres retornar múltiples valores, usa `return a, b, c, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres llenar una matriz de NxN con enteros aleatorios en el range (a, b), lo puedes hacer con esta función:

```
def llenar_matriz(n, a ,b):
    m = []
    for fila in range(n):
        m.append([randint(a, b) for _ in range(n)])

    return m
```

Primero se crea la matriz vacia y luego se le van agregando las filas. Cada fila es una lista de valores generadas con una comprensión de listas:

```
[randint(a, b) for _ in range(n)]
```

#### Demo

```
from random import randint
from pprint import pprint

def llenar_matriz(n, a ,b):
    m = []
    for fila in range(n):
        m.append([randint(a, b) for _ in range(n)])

    return m


resultado = llenar_matriz(5, 1, 100)
pprint(resultado)
```

produce:

```
[[38, 73, 12, 11, 18],
 [50, 61, 85, 40, 5],
 [28, 33, 5, 76, 68],
 [45, 49, 52, 90, 79],
 [64, 89, 46, 63, 70]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Es que son 3 matrices dentro de una lista por eso lo hice de esa forma. Mira te dejo el enunciado uno para que lo veas. Genere una lista de 3 elementos, cada uno de ellos tiene que ser una MATRIZ de 20 filas por 20 columnas
solo con ceros. Son las matrices creada en esa lista que tengo que llenar con numeros aleatorios enteros